# Bib shorts in rain

Tags: clothes, rain

When you ride in a heavy rain, you can easily wear a Gore-tex jacket an to stay "mostly" dry on top and some kind of overshoes to achieve the same for the shoes/socks. However, noone talks about getting wet for the bib shorts? Is there any reasonable solution? Especially on brevets or bikepackings?

Comment: How far/long are you riding?  After a long enough time, you'll likely be thoroughly soaked anyway - no matter what you do.  Water will run down your legs into your shoes, especially if you don't ride with fenders with a good mud flap to keep spray from the front wheel off your lower legs. Water that gets on your neck will run down into your top, soaking your upper body.  If you don't have a rear fender your back can get covered with spray from the rear wheel.  And even if you have all that, if you're riding multiple hours in a hard rain, you're still going to be wet through and through.

Comment: Do you prefer to get soaked in rain water or sweat?

Comment: I am mostly talking about bikepackings where you ride the whole day and you need to arrive somewhere to sleep. Recently I was cycling in Alps where it can get rainy and chilly even during day.

Comment: Summer alpine rain tends to be heavy but fairly brief. In that case I'd maybe put a jacket on, but the rest of my kit would get wet then dry out pretty quickly (re the previous comment)

Comment: I ran a 1/2-marathon in light drizzle a couple of years back. I wore shorts & a shirt. I saw people with rain coats and trash bags and all sorts of other "rain proof" gear. I'm sure I wasn't any more wet with no rain protection than they were wet from all the trapped sweat. I did wear a baseball cap to keep some of the rain out of my eyes.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options.  I've tried them all, they all have different pros/cons

1. Get wet but use a very heavy chamois cream that doesnt wash away easily
2. Waterproof cycling trousers exist. They work well, but are expensive and often hard to find in stock as they are a fairly low volume item
3. MTB shorts are available with various levels of water repellency
4. Bib shorts made with water repellent material exist

Comment: Yup, I never realised but my long bibs were actually water shedding, not water *proof* but certainly helpful in moderate rain, and not too hot otherwise

Comment: *Waterproof cycling trousers exist. They work well*  Your definition of "work well" must be different from mine.  I've tried waterproof cycling trousers.  The problem is "waterproof" works both ways - while water can't get in, neither can it get **out**.  My legs got covered in sweat that couldn't evaporate.  Getting rained on is better - literally.  Nevermind the rubbery material would rub raw spots on my legs, like on the knees.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I use mine for descending big mountain passes in cold+wet conditions.  When used for short durations of extreme conditions waterproof trousers do an excellent job.  What you describe is certainly a drawback and why I said each option has pros/cons

Comment: Ordinary waterproof overtrousers can be worn, but they need to be securely strapped out if the chain and are very hot to wear. I've used them for commuting in heavy snow and found them too hot. Rainlegs are meant to protect the most exposed bits of your legs from the rain without trapping too much sweat but look like they'd be of limited use in stop-start riding.

Answer (score 5):

For 200 km or even 300 km brevets I just get wet legs, but I don't suffer too much from the cold. I have had plenty of rides of that length when I've been unable to dry out for the whole ride, and a couple where the rain has been incessant for the whole ride. Anything longer (and indeed most of my 300s) tends to be at drier times of year when you might get soaked once or twice but you dry out.

Multiple days out in the rain is a challenge whether trekking on foot or bikepacking/touring with a tent. There's a reason people tend to tour in seasons where respite from the rain can be expected. If I was expecting a wet tour I'd look into [Rainlegs](https://www.rainlegs.com/en/home) though wearing waterproof overtrousers as used for hiking can work at low effort (with elastic straps to keep them out of the chain). A pair of MTB-style shorts cut down from waterproof trousers might also be useful.

For multi-day stuff it's important to sleep with dry skin, and have clean dry shorts to wear the next day. This is likely to mean carrying more and/or staying in less remote places every couple of days so there are laundry facilities. Constant wetness softens skin and makes it fragile.

Lower down, shoe covers only hold serious rain off for a little while. They're better against bare skin, so under water-repellent tights or leg warmers, but if (like me) you've got big feet and skinny ankles they've got no hope of sealing completely. Waterproof socks are more effective but only in conditions where you'll be sweating very little

Comment: Implicit in this is that I keep my core reasonably well insulated - legs are sufficiently self-heating when riding, but torsos aren't and cooling there directly affects the important core temperature. Of course cooling the extremities does pull heat from the core, but fast more slowly than a thin wet jersey in the wind

Answer (score 4):

You have three options

1. Ride and get wet.
2. Ride, try to stay dry, get wet anyway.
3. Don't ride.

You can get wet from rain falling down, road water flying up, and sweatting on the inside

**Ambient temperature** The main reason I might try and stay dry is the temperature.  Riding in the rain at 25 degrees C is pleasant, where as 0 degrees C is unpleasant and should be avoided.

**Trying to stay dry** I wear a waterproof jacket and some cheaper waterproof pants.  After a spirited commute, I am frequently drenched in my own sweat and the jacket is wetter on the inside than the outside should the rain let up.  
Some rains demand this outfit.  When it warm rain it is nice to simply ride and use the rain as additional cooling.

**Let yourself get wet** As above, rainwater is extra cooling.  Downside is that it can add weight which can stretch clothes if you get too wet.
Friction is reduced between hands and brake levers/handlebars/etc while increasing at the top of your leg/inseam and saddle.  That can be annoying.

**Road water** is dirty, containing at least mud, and potentially grit and oils and anything else that is laying on the roadway.

The best defence against road water is fenders/mudguards.  Ideally these would be long enough to give 190-200 degrees of coverage over the rear wheel, and 110-120 degrees of coverage on the front wheel.  Short ones help less than long ones.  The guard should also be close to the tyre and wide enough to catch spray off the sides.  
 "ass savers" are perhaps 10% as good as a full guard.

---

Personally on a hard ride/race, I'll wear bib shorts, a thermal shirt as a base layer, and a riding jersey on that.
 Arm warmers, full finger gloves, as well as either tights or leg warmers if I expect to take them off later.   I also wear neoprene shoe covers and carry a light folding raincoat.  Remember to put the pant's cuff over the top of the shoe covers for water shedding.
 I also have a cycling cap with ear flaps, and a neck buff.  With cycling glasses and prescription lenses, the only thing exposed is my nose - covering that with the buff tends to fog up the glasses.

Another trick is to use silicon spray in an aerosol can to douse your waterproof items like jackets, but you can also increase the water shedding of non waterproof items by misting them with silicon.  Don't soak the cloth, just a light layer on the surfaces that get wettest.   Note this may upset some cloth and cause discolouration so test before you commit.

Comment: If you're going to get wet, wind-blocking but non-waterproof stuff is useful for reducing how much you get chilled.  There's some overlap between that and water-repellent in things like gilets, arm/leg warmers and tights, less so in shorts or jerseys.

Comment: *where as 0 degrees C is unpleasant and should be avoided*  Riding in rain at that temperature can be downright deadly - hypothermia is a real threat.  In rain at that temperature, the moment you stop riding you need to get out of the rain, get dry, and get warm as soon as you can.  You won't feel cold when you're riding - because your body is generating a lot of waste heat - your body is about 20% efficient, so if you're putting 100W of power to the pedals you literally have almost 400W of energy keeping you warm. That heat source goes away the moment you stop riding. The cold rain doesn't...

Comment: @AndrewHenle you're right of course, but strangely I've never come across a case of hypothermia from the cold and wet on a bike; I have dealt with it from cold and dry when running an overnight control/feed stop. This might of course be more about how people respond to weather forecasts or a soaking than anything physiological.

Answer (score 3):

Take a change of clothes, in a sealed bag.

Naturally, this will only work in specific circumstances, here are a few that come to my mind:

1. It rained heavily but now cleared up fully, and on the balance of likelihoods, it seems worthwhile to get changed (perhaps keep an eye on the latest hourly forecast).
2. You're cycling on tarmac which dries up quickly.
3. You have somewhere to get changed without offending.

I'm sure there are more things to consider. And it's clearly much easier for shorts than shoes.

Answer (score 3):

If it is raining and warm, I don't do anything to guard against the rain. If it is raining and cool, though, I don't mess around. On a very long effort, your body's ability to regulate its temperature decreases; hard rain and cool temperatures can leave you hypothermic.

In addition to a jacket and rain-resistant bibs, here's what I would pack:

- Full-finger rain-resistant gloves
- Beanie that fits under helmet
- Rain-resistant leg warmers
- Booties. There are some booties that are bulky neoprene and others that are are a thin rubbery layer.

You can probably cram all this into a medium-sized frame bag.

Comment: Also worth having to hand - disposable gloves as in a first aid kit. They're totally waterproof, very light, and will normally go over gloves that turned out to be insufficient. I've never done the need for a hat under my helmet when riding (even with freezing temperatures and precipitation) but a fleece or wool hat is good if you have to stop at the roadside